# Laravel FFMPEG, converting large video on smaller EC2 instances

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg on a laravel project (uploaded on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using t3.micro for now). My problem is that my budget can only go for t3.small but sometimes, I'll have to process large video files like 2GB or even 5GB.

My current set-up can process smaller files like 30MB and convert them to M3U8 (HLS) so there's no problem with the set-up. The problem arises when I'm trying to upload and convert a 2GB file as my EC2 instance only has 1GiB of memory.

Is there a way for FFMPEG (pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg) to "chunk" the conversion so that it uses less memory? Doesn't matter if it takes double the time to convert.

Comment: Not really a Laravel question is it? (primary tag)

Comment: I was thinking if there's an option on the ffmpeg package for laravel to chunk the video files. So I think it's still relevant to Laravel.

Comment: You can segment the input and then convert one segment at a time and then stitch the results together.

Comment: how do you segment it? If I may ask (using the pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg package). I've tried checking the docs but it doesn't say anything about segmenting it.

Comment: Since it's tagged [tag:ffmpeg] refer to the [segment muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment).